# C: bad address in read

Tags: c, io

I am struggling with an incredibly simple task of reading a file once it has been opened. Using perror, I see that the reported error is "bad address". What does this mean and how do I go about fixing it?

```
int freqCheck(char * fileName) {
    /*Allocate buffer*/
    struct stat fileStat;
    stat(fileName, &fileStat);
    int size = fileStat.st_size + 1;
    void * buf = malloc(size);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    if(buf = NULL) {
        printf("An error has occurred while allocating memory\n");
        return 0;
    }/*End if*/

    /*Read file*/
    int fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY); 
    if(fd < 0) {
        perror("Open error");
        return 0;
    }/*End if*/
    ssize_t num;
    while((num = read(fd, buf, size - 1)) > 0) {
        printf("num = %d\n", num);  
    }/*End while*/
    if(num < 0) {
        perror("Read error");
        return 0;
    } else if(num == 0) {
        printf("Read worked!");
    }/*End else if*/

}/*End freqCheck*/
```

Comment: Not related to you problem, but `memset( buf, 0, sizeof(buf))` is not doing what you think it is, and is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It should have been size.

Comment: Not related to the problem: but when you allocate some memory for a pointer you are supposed to check if the allocation failed (i.e ptr == NULL) immediately after you call malloc. You instead have memset immediately after your malloc call. So, if your allocation fails the program will try to write to NULL resulting in an invalid write!

Answer (score 6):

```
if(buf = NULL) {
```

should be

```
if(buf == NULL) {
```

Your compiler should warn you about this common mistake. Don't ignore its warning messages! (If it's not warning you then go turn on warnings, stat!)

Comment: Yep... that's an embarrassing mistake haha